# Is is possible to include other behaviour in a keymapping which would normally invoke a <Plug>?

Tags: key-bindings, plugin

I am working with a plugin which exposes mappings via `<Plug>`. For example, let's say it has a mapping for `<Plug>XYZCommand`. Then, I can put the following in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
nmap a <Plug>XYZCommand
```

... and the key `a` will perform the plugin author's intention.

However, let's say I want to augment that mapping with other behaviour, so I want to add keys and/or invoke a function before or after this call to the `<Plug>` (in the same mapping). Adding keys before the `<Plug>` does not seem to work as it would with any other keymapping. I assume `<Plug>` is special. Is there any other way to achieve what I want without modifying the original plugin?

Comment: `Adding keys before the <Plug> does not seem to work` Actually it should work. Please, give more info on what you're doing. Though I can guess the leading keys do switch from normal to some other mode.

Comment: You can also invoke `<Plug>` mappings manually, though I forget if you need `execute 'normal' "\<Plug>…"` or `feedkeys("\<Plug>…")`; maybe both work

Comment: @Matt apologies, you're quite correct! It does work. I'd tested this earlier, but obviously not thoroughly enough! I can prefix the mapping with extra keys.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble good workaround suggestion!

Comment: Note that _suffixing_ may be harder. For that reason it is common to see `<Plug>(someName)` such that suffixing is more viable